# How to get value in onPanResponderRelease?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to using `PanResponder` in React Native. I want to make draggable component (only ups and down, so I use Y value only). In `onPanResponderMove` I can get live value of Y by getting `gestureState.dy`.

Next, I made helper function that called in `onPanResponderRelease` to reset the position of dragged component when the touch is off. Here is the code:

```
resetPosition() {
    Animated.timing(
      // Animate value over time
      this.position, // The value to drive
      {
        toValue: { x: 0, y: 0 }, // Animate to final value of 1
        duration: 350
      },
    ).start();
  }
```

My question is; how can I get the live Y value when the component from it last position to reset position?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question, it is not entirely clear to me what you want to do?

Comment: @dentemm i want to get live value of gesture.dy inside onPanResponderRelease sir